# Two Bash substitutions in one statement?

Tags: bash

In Bash you can substitute an empty or undefined variable with this:

```
${myvar:-replacement}
```

You can also replace substrings in variables like this:

```
${myvar//replace this/by this}
```

Now I want to combine both substitutions into one: If variable is undefined, set it to `replacement`, otherwise replace a part of it with something else.

I can write this in two lines without problems.

```
myvar=${myvar:-replacement}
myvar=${myvar//replace this/by this}
```

or to more closely reflect my business logic:

```
if [[ -n "${myvar:-}" ]]; then
  myvar="${myvar//replace this/by this}"
else
  myvar="replacement"
fi
```

Is there a way to combine both substitutions into one statement / one line?

I have tried this without success:

```
myvar=${${myvar:-replacement}//replace this/by this}   # bad substitution
```

I am using `set -u` in my scripts so that they error out when I use undefined variables. That's why I need the first sub on undefined var.

Comment: this is not possible in `bash` AFAIK

Comment: Why we always want to do things in one line? If it's readable and not ugly, leave it as is.

Comment: @MarounMaroun you might be right. I just realised I could write both statements in one line, separated by a space. Not sure if that's making it easier or harder to read, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible in Bash.

The best thing you could do is writing them on multiple lines, or use an NOP command, or use utilities:

```
myvar=${myvar:-replacement}
myvar=${myvar/src/dest}
```

```
myvar=$(sed 's/src/dest/g' <<< ${myvar:-defaulttext})
```